# SSH access without opening firewall ports

Tags: ssh, firewall, ssh-tunnel

I have a device running Linux (Debian) installed at a remote location with internet access.

I can't modify the remote location's firewall, and the public IP address is dynamic.

How can I access this machine via SSH from outside the machine's LAN, without modifying the firewall to port-forward port 22 to the machine?

NOTE: I have a web-facing cloud server available with static IP address, and the remote device contacts this server every 5 seconds to retrieve configuration data.  I could push a command to the device if necessary to initiate some sort of reverse SSH tunnel, but I'm not sure how to then utilize that tunnel from the server and/or my local desktop.

Having the ability to SFTP files to the device from either the cloud server or my local desktop would be a huge added bonus.

Thanks for any advice or suggestions on how to accomplish this!

Comment: Downvotes? Why??

Comment: Downvotes without comment can be assumed to be for one of the reasons listed in the downvote arrow hover text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote machine is A
Your cloud server is B
Your desktop/laptop is C

A initiates a SSH session w/ reverse tunnel to B.  This opens a port on B's localhost, pointing back to port 22 on machine A.  All traffic travels over this tunnel.  Check the -R option to the ssh client.

From C you ssh into B, then ssh to the port on the localhost that is the B end of the SSH tunnel that A initiated.

Comment: Good answer. Any way to open a port on B where I could ssh "directly" from C to A, going through B? This would avoid necessity of two ssh connections...

Comment: Yes, check the man page for SSH with the -R option, you can specify what IP to open on the remote (machine B) end.